# Combining & totalling rows in R

Tags: r

I have the below dataset, with the variables as follows:

`member_id` - an id number for each member

`year` - the year in question

`gender` - binary variable, 0 is male, 1 is female

`party` - the party of the member

`Leadership` - `TRUE` if the member holds a leadership position in government or opposition, `FALSE` if they don't

`house_start` - the date the member became an MP

`Year.Entered` - the year they became an MP

`Years.in.parliament` - how many years it has been since they were first elected

`Edu` - the amount of time the MP has participated in debates related to education in the given year.

```
  member_id year gender                   party Leadership house_start Year.Entered Years.in.parliament Edu
1       386 1997      0            Conservative      FALSE  03/05/1979         1979                 18    7
2        37 1997      0                  Labour      FALSE  03/05/1979         1979                 18   10
3        47 1997      0                  Labour       TRUE  09/06/1983         1983                 14  157
4       408 1997      0            Conservative       TRUE  03/05/1979         1979                 18   48
5        15 1997      1        Liberal Democrat      FALSE  09/06/1983         1983                 14    3
6        15 1997      1        Liberal Democrat       TRUE  09/06/1983         1983                 14    9
```

As you can see with rows 5 and 6 in the dataset, the same member is recorded twice in the one year. This has happened throughout the dataset for some members because of the `Leadership` variable. For example this member (id number 15) did not have a leadership position for the first part of 1997 but did get one later in the year. I want to be able to combine these two rows and have the `Leadership` variable as `TRUE` in these cases. I also need to compute the sum of `Edu` rows for these as well, so for this member it would become 12 (because I want each members number of times participated per year for this policy area). So I want it to look like:

```
  member_id year gender                   party Leadership house_start Year.Entered Years.in.parliament Edu
1       386 1997      0            Conservative      FALSE  03/05/1979         1979                 18    7
2        37 1997      0                  Labour      FALSE  03/05/1979         1979                 18   10
3        47 1997      0                  Labour       TRUE  09/06/1983         1983                 14  157
4       408 1997      0            Conservative       TRUE  03/05/1979         1979                 18   48
5        15 1997      1        Liberal Democrat       TRUE  09/06/1983         1983                 14   12
```

I have been trying to change these manually on Excel, but I need to do this for several different policy areas, so it is taking a lot of time. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do a group by `sum` and `arrange` and `slice` the first row

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(member_id, year, gender, party) %>%
     mutate(Edu = sum(Edu)) %>% 
     arrange(party, desc(Leadership)) %>% 
     slice(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

For each group you can select the rows where there is only one row or row where `Leadership` is `TRUE`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(member_id, year, gender, party) %>%
  mutate(Edu = sum(Edu)) %>%
  filter(n() == 1 | Leadership)
```

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding the minimal repeating group is the `member_id` & `year`, we can then sum the Edu amount defensively (using `na.rm = TRUE`) and then slice the grouped data.frame using boolean algebra (taking the maximum of a boolean vector yields true records).

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(member_id, year) %>% 
  mutate(Edu = sum(Edu, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  slice(which.max(Leadership)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Alternatively we can use top_n function (which yields the same result):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(member_id, year) %>% 
  mutate(Edu = sum(Edu, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  top_n(1, Leadership) %>% 
  ungroup()
```